# how to remove whole img element with a SRC value in an UTF-8 string?

Tags: php, image, src

for example this is an algorithm:

```
$text = 'some text1 <img src="1.jpg" />  some text2 <img src="2.jpg">';
if($src == '1.jpg')
   remove(img tag in $text)
echo htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

and result must be:

```
some text1 some text2 <img src="2.jpg>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` directly, no condition and `preg_match` needed.

```
$text = 'some text1 <img src="1.jpg" />  some text2 <img src="2.jpg">';

echo preg_replace('~(<img.*[\'"]1\.jpg[\'"].*>)~', '', $text); // some text1 some text2 <img src="2.jpg">
```

The first `['"]` is needed to avoid removing eg. `a1.jpg` file, the second one is optional. It's better to understand how it works.

**UPDATE**
Due to the comment below, here is updated version with a variable name:

```
$file = '1.jpg';
$text = 'some text1 <img src="1.jpg" />  some text2 <img src="2.jpg" />';
echo preg_replace('~<img[^>]+[\'"]' . $file . '[\'"].*?/>~', '', $text);
```

Comment: $src is not a fix  URL. I must change it to this?: `code`preg_replace('~(<img.*[\'"].'$src'.\.jpg[\'"].*/>)~', '', $text);`code`

Comment: also unknown file extension

Comment: You need to tell to script what src you want to remove. How the script should know what image you want to remove and what not.

Comment: @aliali: you can have filename in separate variable, then it's possible, of course. See my updated answer. Note that I've made a little change in regex too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str_replace()` function to remove all `1.jpg` images.

```
$text = 'some text1 <img src="1.jpg" />  some text2 <img src="2.jpg">';
$text2 = str_replace('<img src="1.jpg" />','',$text);
echo $text2; // Will output "some text1   some text2 "
```

If you want to run this for several `src` values, e.g. in a loop, change line 2 to this:

```
$filename = 'xyz.jpg'; //set this to current filename that you want to remove from the string
$text2 = str_replace('<img src="' . $filename . '" />','',$text);
```

See [PHP manual: str_replace](https://php.net/str_replace) for details.

Comment: Don't provide answer to question, OP don't want to strip all HTML tags.